# How to disable automatic label wrapping in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The image speaks for itself:
[image: Problem]

I want matplotlib to explicitly print the full length y-labels (8 digits total with 6 decimals after the point). But it keeps splitting them into the bias (which can be seen in the top left corner) and the remainder.

I tried disabling the autoscale and setting manual ylims, doesn't help.

Comment: if possible, can you include a code snippet so your plot is reproducible? this will help anyone who wants to take a crack at answering your question

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the default y-ticks using `plt.gca().get_yticks()` and then use `plt.gca().set_yticklabels` to set them to your desired format (documentation for .set_yticklabels is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html) and documentation for .gca is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html)).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

## reproduce your curve
x = np.linspace(31.5,34,500)
y = 3.31*(10**-5)*x**2 - 2.22*(10**-3)*x - 3.68*10**1
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='.')

## retrieve and set yticks
yticks = plt.gca().get_yticks()

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(yticks))
plt.gca().set_yticklabels([f"{y:.6f}" for y in yticks])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.gca().ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)`or `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.6f'))` keep working when you zoom in.